# Grouping by a column and counting number of positive and negative values corresponding to each value in R

Tags: r, count, grouping

I want to have a list of positive and negative values corresponding to each value that comes after grouping a column. My data looks like this:

```
dataset <- read.table(text = 
"id value
1 4
1 -2
1 0
2 6
2 -4
2 -5
2 -1
3 0
3 0
3 -4
3 -5",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
id num_pos_value num_neg_value num_zero_value
1 1 1 1 
2 1 3 0
3 0 2 2
```

I want to extend the columns of the above result by adding sum of the positive and negative values.

```
id num_pos num_neg num_zero sum_pos sum_neg
1 1 1 1 4 -2
2 1 3 0 6 -10
3 0 2 2 0 -9
```

Comment: Pls share a reproducible data for us to try. I think `dplyr::summarise` with `group_by` is all that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a group by 'id' and calculate the `sum` of logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(num_pos = sum(value > 0), 
             num_neg = sum(value < 0), 
             num_zero = sum(value == 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     id num_pos num_neg num_zero
#  <int>   <int>   <int>    <int>
#1     1       1       1        1
#2     2       1       3        0
#3     3       0       2        2
```

---

Or get the `table` of `sign` of 'value' and `spread` it to 'wide'

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(num = list(table(factor(sign(value), levels = -1:1)))) %>%
   unnest %>% 
   mutate(grp = rep(paste0("num", c("pos", "zero", "neg")), 3)) %>% 
   spread(grp, num)
```

---

Or using `count`

```
df1 %>%
   count(id, val = sign(value)) %>% 
   spread(val, n, fill = 0)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
 3L), value = c(4L, -2L, 0L, 6L, -4L, -5L, -1L, 0L, 0L, -4L, -5L
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Or `with(dataset, table(id, sign(value)))` ?

Comment: It works. But can u tell me how to get sum of positive and negative values in the same i.e after grouping by id.

Comment: @SachinThukral In the first option, you can have `num_pos_neg = sum(value != 0)`